# PowerMockito testing legacy code

Tags: java, testing

I am trying to test some legacy code that relies heavily on static method calls.

Basically, I have a class, A, with method b() and c(). A.b() returns void, and A.c() returns a value.

If the real A.b() is called, the class under test throws an exception, so I need it to do nothing. However, if I use:

```
    PowerMockito.spy(A.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(A.class);
```

Then I cannot mock A.c() to return the value that I need. This is because the line

```
PowerMockito.when(A.c()).thenReturn(value);
```

throws an exception: `Only void methods can doNothing()`.

Is there any way to get A.b() to do nothing and "override" A.c() to return the correct value?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around that fixes the issue:

To mock A.c(), use:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
PowerMockito.when(A.c()).thenReturn(value);
```

Then, to do nothing on `A.b()`, add the line:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.method(A.class, "b"));
```

I feel so dirty.

Comment: Doesn't `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(A.class, "b"));` work too?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing your method call after `when()`.

as of PowerMockito API try `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(A.class); A.b();`

Comment: PowerMockito.doNothing().when(A.class) has a void return type